# Get root url with subdirectories in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, iis

So I have this application with multiple libraries installed on them, each with their own api. I want to retrieve the url for every library that will look something like `http://hostname.com/subdir1/subdir2/exampleRoute` without the route ('exampleRoute') because subdir 2 is my root folder, and add `/libraryname` after it so it will look something like  `http://hostname.com/subdir1/subdir2/libraryname`. The amount of subdirs are not fixed, could be more, so if I have 3 subdirs, my root url would be `http://hostname.com/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3`.
I used to do this with `window.location.href` in the root component of my routes, and manually cut the last segment off but this is not the best solution, as I have to be able to get these urls in components that do have a route.

Comment: did you try using ActivatedRoute/ActivatedRouteSnapshot.url?

Comment: I have not, is it possible to get the root route url with that or only current routing state url? eg. hosting on http://hostname.com/subdir1/subdir2/myapp/randomRoute, can I get the  "http://hostname.com/subdir1/subdir2/myapp" part with it in any router state?

Comment: yes there should be no problem retrieving the route url, however the part with the hostname.com is usually added to the main app.config.ts file as a baseUrl variable, I suggest going over the ActivatedRoute and ActivatedRouteSnapshot properties and see ifi any of the stuff there fit your needs.

Comment: you could use `path.basename(path.dirname(filename))`

Answer (score 1):

Your can easily use
`document.head.baseURI` to get what you want.